# Start my service only after docker container is up

Tags: systemd, docker

```
[Unit]
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=10000
RestartSec=5s

WorkingDirectory=...
ExecStart=...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Above is the `.service` file for one of my background tasks, it connects to a docker MySQL database on the same machine.

At boot time, how do I make it run after the docker database is up and connectable?